# Transfer post from one blog to another?

Tags: wordpress

how to send a post from one blog to another? Mean that when we post on one blog it automatically goes to another blog?
I have tried save_post action but did not understand

Comment: There are plugins that aggregate posts from other blogs

Comment: can you mention the name of the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - so assume Site A has all of the posts on it and Site B needs those posts on it too (duplicating content isn't a great idea).

You should run a cron job on Site B that runs a function and checks the RSS feed from Site A and imports the content.

You can use `fetch_feed()` - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed in order to parse the XML and then you can use `wp_insert_post()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post to add them to Site B.

You can then run this cron job every 15 minutes so Site B takes a copy of the posts from Site A.